# How to filter elements of Cartesian product following specific ordering conditions

Tags: python, cartesian-product

I have to generate multiple reactions with different variables. They have 3 elements. Let's call them `B`, `S` and `H`. And they all start with `B1`. `S` can be appended to the element if there is at least one `B`. So it can be `B1S1` or `B2S2` or `B2S1` etc... but not `B1S2`. The same goes for `H`. `B1S1H1` or `B2S2H1` or `B4S1H1` but never `B2S2H3`. The final variation would be `B5S5H5`. I tried with `itertools.product`. But I don't know how to get rid of the elements that don't match my condition and how to add the next element. Here is my code:

```
import itertools

a = list(itertools.product([1, 2, 3, 4], repeat=4))

#print (a)

met = open('random_dat.dat', 'w')
met.write('Reactions')
met.write('\n')
for i in range(1,256): 
    met.write('\n')
    met.write('%s: B%sS%sH%s -> B%sS%sH%s' %(i, a[i][3], a[i][2], a[i][1], a[i][3], a[i][2], a[i][1]))
    met.write('\n')
met.close()
```

Comment: then split the letters and numbers, store numbers in list, and make sure the list is descending. If this is not the case remove the example

Comment: its not really big, so why not use 3 simple nested loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple for loops will do what you want:

```
bsh = []
for b in range(1,6):
    for s in range(1,b+1):
        for h in range(1,b+1):
            bsh.append( f"B{b}S{s}H{h}" )

print(bsh)
```

Output:

```
['B1S1H1', 'B2S1H1', 'B2S1H2', 'B2S2H1', 'B2S2H2', 'B3S1H1', 'B3S1H2', 'B3S1H3', 
 'B3S2H1', 'B3S2H2', 'B3S2H3', 'B3S3H1', 'B3S3H2', 'B3S3H3', 'B4S1H1', 'B4S1H2', 
 'B4S1H3', 'B4S1H4', 'B4S2H1', 'B4S2H2', 'B4S2H3', 'B4S2H4', 'B4S3H1', 'B4S3H2', 
 'B4S3H3', 'B4S3H4', 'B4S4H1', 'B4S4H2', 'B4S4H3', 'B4S4H4', 'B5S1H1', 'B5S1H2', 
 'B5S1H3', 'B5S1H4', 'B5S1H5', 'B5S2H1', 'B5S2H2', 'B5S2H3', 'B5S2H4', 'B5S2H5', 
 'B5S3H1', 'B5S3H2', 'B5S3H3', 'B5S3H4', 'B5S3H5', 'B5S4H1', 'B5S4H2', 'B5S4H3', 
 'B5S4H4', 'B5S4H5', 'B5S5H1', 'B5S5H2', 'B5S5H3', 'B5S5H4', 'B5S5H5']
```

---

Thanks to [@mikuszefski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/803359/mikuszefski) for pointing out improvements.

Comment: why not `for s in range(b)`?

Comment: i think it's h > s. But he did not give an explicit example.

Comment: @mik good suggestion, but du to `range`'s exclusive upper limit it would be range(1,b+1)

Comment: Sure, and as B5 is allowed range should go to 6

Answer (score 0):

Patrick his answer in list comprehension style

```
bsh = [f"B{b}S{s}H{h}" for b in range(1,5) for s in range(1,b+1) for h in range(1,b+1)]
```

Gives

```
['B1S1H1',
 'B2S1H1',
 'B2S1H2',
 'B2S2H1',
 'B2S2H2',
 'B3S1H1',
 'B3S1H2',
 'B3S1H3',
 'B3S2H1',
 'B3S2H2',
 'B3S2H3',
 'B3S3H1',
 'B3S3H2',
 'B3S3H3',
 'B4S1H1',
 'B4S1H2',
 'B4S1H3',
 'B4S1H4',
 'B4S2H1',
 'B4S2H2',
 'B4S2H3',
 'B4S2H4',
 'B4S3H1',
 'B4S3H2',
 'B4S3H3',
 'B4S3H4',
 'B4S4H1',
 'B4S4H2',
 'B4S4H3',
 'B4S4H4']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would implement your "use `itertools.product` and get rid off unnecessary elements" solution following way:

```
import itertools
a = list(itertools.product([1,2,3,4,5],repeat=3))
a = [i for i in a if (i[1]<=i[0] and i[2]<=i[1] and i[2]<=i[0])]
```

Note that I assumed last elements needs to be smaller or equal than any other. Note that `a` is now `list` of 35 `tuple`s each holding 3 `int`s. So you need to made `str`s of them for example using so-called f-string:

```
a = [f"B{i[0]}S{i[1]}H{i[2]}" for i in a]
print(a)
```

output:

```
['B1S1H1', 'B2S1H1', 'B2S2H1', 'B2S2H2', 'B3S1H1', 'B3S2H1', 'B3S2H2', 'B3S3H1', 'B3S3H2', 'B3S3H3', 'B4S1H1', 'B4S2H1', 'B4S2H2', 'B4S3H1', 'B4S3H2', 'B4S3H3', 'B4S4H1', 'B4S4H2', 'B4S4H3', 'B4S4H4', 'B5S1H1', 'B5S2H1', 'B5S2H2', 'B5S3H1', 'B5S3H2', 'B5S3H3', 'B5S4H1', 'B5S4H2', 'B5S4H3', 'B5S4H4', 'B5S5H1', 'B5S5H2', 'B5S5H3', 'B5S5H4', 'B5S5H5']
```

However you might also use another methods of formatting instead of f-string if you wish.